# what happen to the spawned process if the module who spawns it dies?

Tags: multithreading, erlang

If a module A has a method someMethod(). If this method is spawned as a thread from this module A, and if the code inside someMethod() is an infinite loop, then in this case if Module A goes down, will the spawned thread executing "someMethod" will also go down ?

Basically I want to know if there are multiple threads spawned from a module, and if this module goes down, will those all the spawned threads will go down/killed automatically ? or they will keep on running (assuming the code which is being executed by these threads is and infinite loop)

Answer (score 3):

Modules don't go down. Processes do. Modules could be purged out from the memory if you have more then one new version loaded up and then all processes which run the old version will be killed but it is not what you asked. Modules don't go down. Processes do.

Answer (score 1):

In Erlang, the process A spawns the other process B. Depending on what behaviors you want B continue do....if process B do the job that dont relate to data or need communicate to process A such as links A and B or monitor A, process B will do any thing for you and dont care about process A.

This is reason why some big telecommunication systems have Fallover/Takeover behavior to solve this problem. They need 2 main processes run parallel and monitor each other. For example: A is sub and B is main, both of them together monitor a thousands son's processes (S1, S2, S3...).

[image]

when process B get an issue, process A will immediately take data from process and continue what their son and then restarting process B. All of them depend on what behavior of your application that you want to build

Answer (score 0):

In case you are asking:

> If I spawn two processes that execute the same function in a module,
>   and the first process dies, does the second process also die?

Try this:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

get_divisor(X, Id) when is_integer(X) ->
    Result = 10/X,
    io:format("Process ~w: 10/~w = ~w~n", [Id, X, Result]),
    timer:sleep(1000),
    get_divisor(X-1, Id).

test() ->
    Pid1 = spawn(my, get_divisor, [10, harry]),
    Pid2 = spawn(my, get_divisor, [20, sally]),
    io:format("harry's pid = ~w~nsally's pid = ~w~n", [Pid1, Pid2]).
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]



   Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)
    1> c(my).    
    my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
    {ok,my}

    2> my:test().
    harry's pid = <0.71.0>
    sally's pid = <0.72.0>
    Process harry: 10/10 = 1.0
    Process sally: 10/20 = 0.5
    ok
    Process harry: 10/9 = 1.1111111111111112
    Process sally: 10/19 = 0.5263157894736842
    Process harry: 10/8 = 1.25
    Process sally: 10/18 = 0.5555555555555556
```

After the output starts, quickly issue the `i() command` (info) in the shell:

```
3> i().
Pid                   Initial Call                          Heap     Reds Msgs
Registered            Current Function                     Stack              
<0.0.0>               otp_ring0:start/2                      376      990    0
init                  init:loop/1                              2              
<0.1.0>               erts_code_purger:start/0               233       11    0
erts_code_purger      erts_code_purger:wait_for_request        0              
<0.2.0>               erts_literal_area_collector:start      233        3    0
                      erts_literal_area_collector:msg_l        5              
<0.3.0>               erts_dirty_process_code_checker:s      233        3    0
                      erts_dirty_process_code_checker:m        1              
<0.6.0>               erlang:apply/2                        6772   713103    0
erl_prim_loader       erl_prim_loader:loop/3                   5              
<0.32.0>              gen_event:init_it/6                    987      414    0
error_logger          gen_event:fetch_msg/6                   10              
<0.33.0>              erlang:apply/2                        1598      954    0
application_controlle gen_server:loop/7                        7              
<0.35.0>              application_master:init/4              233       69    0
                      application_master:main_loop/2           7              
<0.36.0>              application_master:start_it/4          233       90    0
                      application_master:loop_it/4             5              
<0.37.0>              supervisor:kernel/1                    987     2202    0
kernel_sup            gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.38.0>              erlang:apply/2                        6772   142009    0
code_server           code_server:loop/1                       3              
<0.40.0>              rpc:init/1                             233       32    0
rex                   gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.41.0>              global:init/1                          233       63    0
global_name_server    gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.42.0>              erlang:apply/2                         233       25    0
                      global:loop_the_locker/1                 5              
<0.43.0>              erlang:apply/2                         233        3    0
                      global:loop_the_registrar/0              2              
<0.44.0>              inet_db:init/1                         233      350    0
inet_db               gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.45.0>              global_group:init/1                    233       74    0
global_group          gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.46.0>              file_server:init/1                    1598     3436    0
file_server_2         gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.47.0>              gen_event:init_it/6                    233       51    0
erl_signal_server     gen_event:fetch_msg/6                   10              
<0.48.0>              supervisor_bridge:standard_error/      233       50    0
standard_error_sup    gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.49.0>              erlang:apply/2                         233       11    0
standard_error        standard_error:server_loop/1             2              
<0.50.0>              supervisor_bridge:user_sup/1           233       72    0
                      gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.51.0>              user_drv:server/2                     1598     7176    0
user_drv              user_drv:server_loop/6                   9              
<0.52.0>              group:server/3                         233       88    0
user                  group:server_loop/3                      4              
<0.53.0>              group:server/3                      196650    89053    0
                      group:server_loop/3                      4              
<0.54.0>              kernel_config:init/1                   233       48    0
                      gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.55.0>              supervisor:kernel/1                    376      282    0
kernel_safe_sup       gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.59.0>              supervisor:disk_log_sup/1              233      147    0
disk_log_sup          gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.60.0>              disk_log_server:init/1                 610       91    0
disk_log_server       gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.61.0>              disk_log:init/2                       6772    36424    0
                      disk_log:loop/1                          5              
<0.63.0>              erlang:apply/2                       17731     4082    0
                      shell:shell_rep/4                       17              
<0.64.0>              erlang:apply/2                      318187    45309    0
                      c:pinfo/1                               50              
<0.71.0>              my:get_divisor/2                       233       59    0
                      timer:sleep/1                            5              
<0.72.0>              my:get_divisor/2                       233       59    0
                      timer:sleep/1                            5              
Total                                                     565674  1046833    0
                                                             283              
ok
```

At the bottom of the output above, you can see that `my:get_divisor/2` is running in process `<0.71.0>` as well as in process `<0.72.0>`.  And, if you look at the output for iex line `2>`, you can see:

```
    2> my:test().
    harry's pid = <0.71.0>
    sally's pid = <0.72.0>
```

which confirms that those are the processes that the `test()` function spawned.

The output from the two spawned processes continues:

```
Process harry: 10/7 = 1.4285714285714286
Process sally: 10/17 = 0.5882352941176471
Process harry: 10/6 = 1.6666666666666667
Process sally: 10/16 = 0.625
Process harry: 10/5 = 2.0
Process sally: 10/15 = 0.6666666666666666
Process harry: 10/4 = 2.5
Process sally: 10/14 = 0.7142857142857143
Process harry: 10/3 = 3.3333333333333335
Process sally: 10/13 = 0.7692307692307693
Process harry: 10/2 = 5.0
Process sally: 10/12 = 0.8333333333333334
Process harry: 10/1 = 10.0
Process sally: 10/11 = 0.9090909090909091
Process sally: 10/10 = 1.0
4> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2019::20:40:51 ===
Error in process <0.71.0> with exit value:
{badarith,[{my,get_divisor,2,[{file,"my.erl"},{line,5}]}]}
```

The last line says that process `<0.71.0>`, i.e. process `harry`, had an error, yet sally's output continues:

```
Process sally: 10/9 = 1.1111111111111112
Process sally: 10/8 = 1.25
Process sally: 10/7 = 1.4285714285714286
Process sally: 10/6 = 1.6666666666666667
Process sally: 10/5 = 2.0
Process sally: 10/4 = 2.5
Process sally: 10/3 = 3.3333333333333335
Process sally: 10/2 = 5.0
Process sally: 10/1 = 10.0
4> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2019::20:41:01 ===
Error in process <0.72.0> with exit value:
{badarith,[{my,get_divisor,2,[{file,"my.erl"},{line,5}]}]}
```

The last line above shows that now process `<0.72.0>`, i.e. process `sally`, had an error.

If you use the `i() command` again, you will see that neither of the processes `<0.71.0>` and `<0.72.0>` is running anymore.

```
i().
Pid                   Initial Call                          Heap     Reds Msgs
Registered            Current Function                     Stack              
<0.0.0>               otp_ring0:start/2                      376      990    0
init                  init:loop/1                              2              
<0.1.0>               erts_code_purger:start/0               233       11    0
erts_code_purger      erts_code_purger:wait_for_request        0              
<0.2.0>               erts_literal_area_collector:start      233        3    0
                      erts_literal_area_collector:msg_l        5              
<0.3.0>               erts_dirty_process_code_checker:s      233        3    0
                      erts_dirty_process_code_checker:m        1              
<0.6.0>               erlang:apply/2                        6772   714364    0
erl_prim_loader       erl_prim_loader:loop/3                   5              
<0.32.0>              gen_event:init_it/6                   2586     3251    0
error_logger          gen_event:fetch_msg/6                   10              
<0.33.0>              erlang:apply/2                        1598      954    0
application_controlle gen_server:loop/7                        7              
<0.35.0>              application_master:init/4              233       69    0
                      application_master:main_loop/2           7              
<0.36.0>              application_master:start_it/4          233       90    0
                      application_master:loop_it/4             5              
<0.37.0>              supervisor:kernel/1                    987     2202    0
kernel_sup            gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.38.0>              erlang:apply/2                        6772   142119    0
code_server           code_server:loop/1                       3              
<0.40.0>              rpc:init/1                             233       32    0
rex                   gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.41.0>              global:init/1                          233       63    0
global_name_server    gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.42.0>              erlang:apply/2                         233       25    0
                      global:loop_the_locker/1                 5              
<0.43.0>              erlang:apply/2                         233        3    0
                      global:loop_the_registrar/0              2              
<0.44.0>              inet_db:init/1                         233      350    0
inet_db               gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.45.0>              global_group:init/1                    233       74    0
global_group          gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.46.0>              file_server:init/1                    1598     3436    0
file_server_2         gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.47.0>              gen_event:init_it/6                    233       51    0
erl_signal_server     gen_event:fetch_msg/6                   10              
<0.48.0>              supervisor_bridge:standard_error/      233       50    0
standard_error_sup    gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.49.0>              erlang:apply/2                         233       11    0
standard_error        standard_error:server_loop/1             2              
<0.50.0>              supervisor_bridge:user_sup/1           233       72    0
                      gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.51.0>              user_drv:server/2                      987    19868    0
user_drv              user_drv:server_loop/6                   9              
<0.52.0>              group:server/3                         233      114    0
user                  group:server_loop/3                      4              
<0.53.0>              group:server/3                      196650   153779    0
                      group:server_loop/3                      4              
<0.54.0>              kernel_config:init/1                   233       48    0
                      gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.55.0>              supervisor:kernel/1                    376      282    0
kernel_safe_sup       gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.59.0>              supervisor:disk_log_sup/1              233      147    0
disk_log_sup          gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.60.0>              disk_log_server:init/1                 610       91    0
disk_log_server       gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.61.0>              disk_log:init/2                       6772    36600    0
                      disk_log:loop/1                          5              
<0.63.0>              erlang:apply/2                       17731     4277    0
                      shell:shell_rep/4                       17              
<0.64.0>              erlang:apply/2                      318187    81397    0
                      c:pinfo/1                               50              
Total                                                     566196  1164826    0
                                                             273              
ok
5>
```

Erlang also allows you to `link` a process to another process, which will cause both processes to die if either process dies:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

get_divisor(X, Id) when is_integer(X) ->
    Result = 10/X,
    io:format("Process ~w: 10/~w = ~w~n", [Id, X, Result]),
    timer:sleep(1000),
    get_divisor(X-1, Id).

test() ->
    Pid1 = spawn_link(my, get_divisor, [10, harry]),
    Pid2 = spawn_link(my, get_divisor, [20, sally]),

    io:format("shell pid = ~w~n", [self()]), 
    io:format("harry's pid = ~w~nsally's pid = ~w~n", [Pid1, Pid2]).
```

"spawn_link()" can be read as "spawn_and_link()".  In `test()`, both processes will be linked to the shell process (because I will call `test()` in the shell, and the process calling `spawn_link()` is the other side of the link).  Then, if Pid1 dies, Pid1 will cause the shell process to die, and because the shell process is linked to Pid2 that means Pid2 will also die. By the way, when the shell process dies, another shell process (with a different pid) is automatically started.

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)
1> c(my).    
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}
2> my:test().
shell pid = <0.64.0>
Process harry: 10/10 = 1.0
Process sally: 10/20 = 0.5
harry's pid = <0.71.0>
sally's pid = <0.72.0>
ok
Process harry: 10/9 = 1.1111111111111112
Process sally: 10/19 = 0.5263157894736842
Process harry: 10/8 = 1.25
Process sally: 10/18 = 0.5555555555555556
Process harry: 10/7 = 1.4285714285714286
Process sally: 10/17 = 0.5882352941176471
Process harry: 10/6 = 1.6666666666666667
Process sally: 10/16 = 0.625
Process harry: 10/5 = 2.0
Process sally: 10/15 = 0.6666666666666666
Process harry: 10/4 = 2.5
Process sally: 10/14 = 0.7142857142857143
Process harry: 10/3 = 3.3333333333333335
Process sally: 10/13 = 0.7692307692307693
Process harry: 10/2 = 5.0
Process sally: 10/12 = 0.8333333333333334
Process harry: 10/1 = 10.0
Process sally: 10/11 = 0.9090909090909091
Process sally: 10/10 = 1.0
** exception error: an error occurred when evaluating an arithmetic expression
     in function  my:get_divisor/2 (my.erl, line 5)
3> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 11-May-2019::12:06:18 ===
Error in process <0.71.0> with exit value:
{badarith,[{my,get_divisor,2,[{file,"my.erl"},{line,5}]}]}
```

And that's the end of the output. You don't see an error from process `<0.72.0>` because when process `<0.71.0>` died, it caused the shell to die(even though the output of those error messages is reversed), and the new shell that was automatically started doesn't know anything about process `<0.72.0>`, and therefore the new shell process doesn't output process `<0.72.0>`'s error messages.

If you use `i()`, you can see that none of the following processes is running:

```
shell process = <0.64.0>
...
...
harry's pid = <0.71.0>
sally's pid = <0.72.0>


3> i().
=ERROR REPORT==== 10-May-2019::21:17:19 ===
Error in process <0.71.0> with exit value:
{badarith,[{my,get_divisor,2,[{file,"my.erl"},{line,5}]}]}
3> i().      
Pid                   Initial Call                          Heap     Reds Msgs
Registered            Current Function                     Stack              
<0.0.0>               otp_ring0:start/2                      376      990    0
init                  init:loop/1                              2              
<0.1.0>               erts_code_purger:start/0               233       11    0
erts_code_purger      erts_code_purger:wait_for_request        0              
<0.2.0>               erts_literal_area_collector:start      233        3    0
                      erts_literal_area_collector:msg_l        5              
<0.3.0>               erts_dirty_process_code_checker:s      233        3    0
                      erts_dirty_process_code_checker:m        1              
<0.6.0>               erlang:apply/2                        6772   714804    0
erl_prim_loader       erl_prim_loader:loop/3                   5              
<0.32.0>              gen_event:init_it/6                   1598     1848    0
error_logger          gen_event:fetch_msg/6                   10              
<0.33.0>              erlang:apply/2                        1598      954    0
application_controlle gen_server:loop/7                        7              
<0.35.0>              application_master:init/4              233       69    0
                      application_master:main_loop/2           7              
<0.36.0>              application_master:start_it/4          233       90    0
                      application_master:loop_it/4             5              
<0.37.0>              supervisor:kernel/1                    987     2202    0
kernel_sup            gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.38.0>              erlang:apply/2                        6772   142113    0
code_server           code_server:loop/1                       3              
<0.40.0>              rpc:init/1                             233       32    0
rex                   gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.41.0>              global:init/1                          233       63    0
global_name_server    gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.42.0>              erlang:apply/2                         233       25    0
                      global:loop_the_locker/1                 5              
<0.43.0>              erlang:apply/2                         233        3    0
                      global:loop_the_registrar/0              2              
<0.44.0>              inet_db:init/1                         233      350    0
inet_db               gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.45.0>              global_group:init/1                    233       74    0
global_group          gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.46.0>              file_server:init/1                    1598     3436    0
file_server_2         gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.47.0>              gen_event:init_it/6                    233       51    0
erl_signal_server     gen_event:fetch_msg/6                   10              
<0.48.0>              supervisor_bridge:standard_error/      233       50    0
standard_error_sup    gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.49.0>              erlang:apply/2                         233       11    0
standard_error        standard_error:server_loop/1             2              
<0.50.0>              supervisor_bridge:user_sup/1           233       72    0
                      gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.51.0>              user_drv:server/2                     2586    12209    0
user_drv              user_drv:server_loop/6                   9              
<0.52.0>              group:server/3                         233      101    0
user                  group:server_loop/3                      4              
<0.53.0>              group:server/3                      318187    86312    0
                      group:server_loop/3                      4              
<0.54.0>              kernel_config:init/1                   233       48    0
                      gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.55.0>              supervisor:kernel/1                    376      282    0
kernel_safe_sup       gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.59.0>              supervisor:disk_log_sup/1              233      147    0
disk_log_sup          gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.60.0>              disk_log_server:init/1                 610       91    0
disk_log_server       gen_server:loop/7                       10              
<0.61.0>              disk_log:init/2                       6772    37458    0
                      disk_log:loop/1                          5              
<0.63.0>              erlang:apply/2                       17731     4978    0
                      shell:shell_rep/4                       17              
<0.74.0>              erlang:apply/2                      318187    39091    0
                      c:pinfo/1                               50              
Total                                                     688344  1047971    0
                                                             273              
ok
4>
```